# Как изменить объект во время анимации?

Tags: java, android, анимация, android-animation

В примере простая анимация перемещения объекта из точки А в Б. Объект двигается по нажатию кнопки. Есть ли возможность взаимодействия с объектом во время движения? Например изменения изображения на другое по нажатию.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationSet;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView ImageV1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageV1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageV1);

        Button startFall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btn1);

        final Animation fallAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.falling);

        startFall.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ImageV1.startAnimation(fallAnim);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Сама анимация:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

    <translate
        android:duration="3000"
        android:fromYDelta="1500"
        android:toYDelta="-100%" />

</set>
```

Пример слушателя (не реагирует на нажатия движущегося обьекта)

```
fallAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                ImageV1.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    startFall.setText("Прослушал удачно");
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Вам необходимо работать с Property Animation, а не с VIew. 
Смотрите в сторону ObjectAnimator. И не с Drawble Animation...

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei Подскажите пожалуйста насчет совместимости с устройствами на базе API10+, будут ли данные методы работать со старым API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Повесьте слушатель на анимацию.
2. При её старте, в методе `onAnimationStart()`, поменяйте слушатель нажатий у вьюхи.
3. При её завершении (`onAnimationEnd()`) - поменяйте обратно.

Слушатель на анимацию вешать можно так:

```
fallAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Можно пожалуйста более конкретно описать второй пункт. Я только начинаю разбираться.

Comment: @ВАНЕЧКА, обновил ответ

Comment: Если быть честным, то я разобрался как повесить слушатель на анимацию, не не понял что значит поменять слушатель нажатий у вьюхи, и еще больше понял зачем менять его обратно.

Если правильно понял то задаю слушатель для вьхи вот так, но ничего не происходит при нажатии.
ImageV1.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    startFall.setText("Прослушал удачно");
                    }
                });

Comment: @ВАНЕЧКА, ну, вы же сами говорите, что вам надо что-то поменять по нажатию - вот я и предлагаю повесить слушатель нажатий и в нём что-то поменять где-то. Вы не очень явно заявляете о том, что вам нужно и что именно у вас затруднения вызывает. Засим я не могу вам дать точный ответ.

Comment: Моя цель это вывод порядка 50 изображений, в 3 строки которые будут двигаться по экрану от точки а в точку б по вертикали. И соответсвенно я хочу иметь возможность влиять на эти элементы, например при нажатии что бы любое изображение могло измениться на другое, заранее установленное.

Я привел пример слушателя который использую, но это не приносит какого  то виимого результата.

Comment: Я еще потестировал поведение приложения, и выяснил что слушатель вьюхи работает. Однако он реагирует только если тапать по изначальному положению изображения, и не работает если тапать по изображению во время анимации, те по движущемуся обьекту. 
Подскажите, если ли возможность реагировать именно в движении?

Comment: @ВАНЕЧКА, опробуйте сделать анимацию через `View.animate()` у такого способа анимирования с API>=19 можно вешать `OnAnimationUpdateListener`, в коем можно попробовать проставлять самой вьюхе координаты, соответствующие координатам анимации. Так должна, по идее, область клика попровиться. Ну или разбить вашу анимацию на множество мелких и в их начале-конце проставлять координаты вьюхе...

Comment: К сожалению ограничен версией api, min не больше 16. Но спасибо за помощь :)